# diremption vs disremption

Tags: meaning

Is *disremption* simply another way of writing *diremption*?

Some examples for usage of *disrempt*/*disremption* from books:

> ... the state as such is not so much the result as the beginning. It is within the State that the family is first developed into civil society, and it is the Idea of the State itself which disrempts itself into two moments.

> ... this has been the motif since the Kantian disremption of the Pure from the Practical Reason.

> The A and B will persist in falling apart , for every attempt to introduce a mediating term ends in further disremption.

Comment: Both words are very rare.  There is some suggestion that they mean the same thing, but, absent definitive definitions, it's hard to say with any certainty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, it is reasonable to assume that the meanings are the same, because *dis-* an *di-* are alternative forms of the same Latin prefix. Usually, it is, however, fairly well settled which form of the prefix will appear in which word, and *diremption* is by far the more frequent spelling of this very rare word (which is typically found in the contexts that have to do with Hegelianism). It is anybody's guess why the authors you quote have chosen the alternative spelling of the word, but there is nothing in the quoted sentences that would indicate that what they intended is anything different from diremption.

Comment: Thanks for this very helpful answer.